# Flash TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. - when accessing TLFTextField from Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, typeerror, document-class

I'm lost on this one. I receive a `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` output message the first time my Document Class tries to access a simple textfield on the stage (added from the IDE, not actionscript)

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import fl.text.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    private var _netConnection:NetConnection;
    private var _responder:Responder;
    /* some other public + private vars */

    public function Main() {
        init();
    }

    public function init(e:*=null):void {
        _netConnection = new NetConnection();
        _responder = new Responder(uponResult);

        txt.text = "init()";
    }
    /* more functions */
  }
}
```

I tried adding `txt.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, init);` incase the txt TLFTextField wasn't ... there... at the beginning, but it still outputs the error.

I feel like a bit of an idiot atm, what's the prognosis doc?
JB

Comment: it depends on how and where you initialize your `txt`. Could you post the code for that?

Comment: txt is manually added to the stage via the Flash IDE, not via actionscript.

Comment: if txt isn't there, you can't add an event listener to it, either... Have you tried calling init on your document class' Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE?

Comment: I did now, thanks weltraumpirat and heartcode :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLFTextFields are weird creatures, I've had a lot of issues with them recently.

I'd try to use the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event because the TLFTextFields have to be on the stage when you try to access them:

```
public function Main() {
  addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
};
public function init(e:Event):void {
  removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  txt.text = "init()";
};
```

It should work if your TLFTextField is on the first frame on the Main Timeline.

Let me know if this one does the magic,

Rob

Comment: That did the trick, Rob, thanks kindly!

One other thing that stumped me is that TLFTextFields seem only to work properly when they are selectable or editable, not when read-only. Is this an actionscript bug, or do you need to do extra things to make it work correctly?

Comment: TLFTextField is still a beta feature and full of bugs unfortunately. I'd say try to read up on it as much as you can and if you've got stuck with your code, come back here :)